# While Loops and condition of it

Tags: python, loops

I don't know why my While loop condition doesn't work. This is my code:

```
randomNumber = 2
chosenNumber = ""
while chosenNumber != randomNumber:
    chosenNumber = input("Please enter a number: ")
```

For example, when I enter 2 for chosenNumber, it still loops and asks me to enter a number. But 2 is equal to randomNumber, why doesn't the While loop stop executing?

Comment: Because a string, like `"2"` is not equal to a number, like `2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: Need to compare a sting to string or int to int.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string. So convert it to `int` before comparison

```
while chosenNumber != randomNumber:
    chosenNumber = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if chosenNumber.isdigit():
        chosenNumber = int(chosenNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm a beginner and you guys help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
randomNumber = 2
chosenNumber = float("inf")
while chosenNumber != randomNumber:
    chosenNumber = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I did that! Thanksss